# git log -S does not show anything

Tags: git, git-log

I've used `git log -S` many times with great success but this time, it does not show anything.
I'm looking for the commit that introduced `pagesNum`.

Here is what I do:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git grep pagesNum
resources/locales/en.json:    "search-page": "{pagesNum} Select...",
$ git log -SpagesNum
$ git log -S"pagesNum"
$ git log -S"pagesNum" --all
$
```

How is it possible that `git log` does not show anything??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `-S` does not consider text that was introduced in a merge commit.

I just tested this by committing and empty commit, and then merging it, but adding a change. Doing this causes `git grep` to find the text, but `git log -S` shows nothing.

As a remedy, try the `-m` option with `git log` which considers the diff to all parents, although you will probably also want to add the `--first-parent` option to only consider the diff to the main parent. However, `--first-parent` will only show the merge commit that introduced the change, and not the regular commit, if applicable. Unfortunately, there is no way to modify the `-m` option to show only the first parent without having that option apply to the selection of commits as well.

Comment: In fact `git log -SpagesNum -m --first-parent` gave me the merge commit that introduced `pagesNum`. Thanks!